# Truncate text with implode

Tags: php, text, truncate, ellipsis

Is it possible to truncate text (with x characters and ellipsis) along with implode? Sorry if this is a silly question but I've tried all the truncate methods I can find on here and none seem to work for me.

Here's the code I want to truncate the text on. Thanks for your help!

```
<?php if(!empty($this->row->extraData->bottom)) { echo implode("\r\n",$this->row->extraData->bottom);} ?>
```

Comment: You should probably do that on the client side using css and / or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't elegant but it gets the job done for having it in one line.

```
$maxLength = 10;
if(!empty($this->row->extraData->bottom)) { 

    function truncateArrStrings($arr, $max) {
        $outputArr = array();
        foreach($arr as $value) {
            if(strlen($value) > $max) {
                $outputArr[] = substr($value, 0, $max) . '...';
            } else {
                $outputArr[] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $outputArr;
    }
    echo implode("\r\n",truncateArrStrings($this->row->extraData->bottom, $maxLength));
}
```